# Spivak Chapter 7 Question 13: Clarification

Tags: calculus, analysis

In question 13 b of chapter 7 of Spivak, I'm being asked to prove that if a function satisfies the conclusion of the intermediate value theorem, and if that function takes on each value only once, it is continuous. I don't see why this is true, however. Let $f(x) = x$ in the interval $[1, 2)$, and 2 when x = 3. Then f(x) satisfies the conclusion of the intermediate value theorem on [1, 3], but isn't continuous. Could someone explain to me why this isn't a counterexample for the given statement, or if I've misinterpreted the question? **Could you also avoid giving hints on how to solve this problem? I would still like to attempt solving this question.**

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You function is not defined on $(2,3)$.

Comment: @Koro Just to check - does the IVT specify that the function must be defined on an interval [a,b]? Because Spivak doesn't specify this (or maybe I've missed it somewhere?) but it does say so on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem.

Comment: The result you seek to prove is this: let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be a function which has intermediate value property on $[a, b] $ and let $f$ be one-one function then $f$ is continuous on $[a, b] $.

Comment: Real valued function $f$ has to be defined on an interval (that is, a connected set) for IVT to hold good.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: You’re welcome. Just let me know if you want proof (or any hint in proving) of this. I’m not dropping any hints as you mentioned in your post.